# How to create a XAML Basic Page item in Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate?

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

In multiple Windows Store App tutorials i have come across, where Visual Studio 2012 is used, the user is told to delete MainPage.xaml and replace it with a new item called Basic Page.
[image: VS 2012 Basic Page]

Since Windows Store Apps is not available in the version I'm using (Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate), when creating a new project, I went with Windows Universal Blank App. The problem is I can't find the Basic Page item in the version I'm using. 
[image: VS 2015 Basic Page not available]

Is there an equivalent item I can use instead?

**Edit:** [YouTube tutorial link](https://youtu.be/siVlecgI5CQ)

I know absolutely nothing about Windows Store Apps and Universal Apps, but was told by my CS teacher that I should use Windows Universal App, when creating the project. The tutorial was his recommendation, and he expects that I finish it during the weekend, so I can't ask him about it. I'm guessing there must be some difference between WSA and WUA. I can't see any item that looks like Basic Page, and I don't really know why the guy is replacing the MainPage.xaml with a Basic Page, so i'm clueless about what to do now.

Comment: 1) in the tutorials, look at what the basic page looks like 2) go through templates in 2015 until you find a rough equivalent?

Comment: @Will Thanks, but it didn't really help me. I added an edit with some context to my question.

Comment: Is there anything really special about a Basic Page?  You might be able to skip that step and go with the defaults given to you in the WUA template.  Sorry, can't help much more than these WAGs, as I haven't WSA/WUA'd.  (sneaks a look at the tutorial) eew.  Gross.  That guy is using the visual editor.  Stinky.  Why not just go find a nice simple hello world tutorial built against WUAs?  There's bound to be lots of them, (use your search engine!) and you won't have to worry about finding equivalents for WSA concepts.  Your prof isn't faultless, he may have steered you wrong.

Comment: Thanks for trying though. I think your right about finding another tutorial, but thought it wouldn't hurt to ask here first. Maybe someone knew what to do in this situation since I'm probably not the first guy to stumble upon tutorials like this even though I couldn't find an answer when I searched for a solution. Btw. the book called "Head First C#" is a part of the curriculum in my class, and I also stumbled upon this Basic Page thing there, which is another reason I thought it could be interesting to find an answer to my question. But I'll find another tutorial like you proposed.

Comment: Someone might still come along and tell you exactly what you need... maybe :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `Blank Page` option instead. 
Difference between `Basic Page` and `Blank Page`
**Basic Page**- This on addition also adds some boilerplate code related to navigation inside your app along with back button and Appname header in XAML code.
**Blank Page**- Only adds a default page with basic navigation.
Make sure you have installed app development SDK's, since under C# you are supposed to get Universal option which I am not seeing in your current screenshot.
If you install Windows 8.1 SDK then you might get Basic Page template option. But for windows 10 SDK you can use [Template10](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10) add it as nuget package which already contains these navigation related boilerplate codes.

Comment: Nice answer. I now have an idea of the differences between the Basic Page and Blank Page. I was worried that the Basic Page included some stuff i was going to need later. However, I went with another tutorial focusing on making UWP apps instead of the one I linked to in my question. I'll also give the Template10 documentation a look. It looks interesting.

Comment: Temoplate10 is great as you get Splitview functionality combined with other Boilerplates. We had to write these codes in every project for windows 8.1 when it was required. Since you are beginner would give you a golden advice follow this [Bob Tabor tutorial](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners). You will more easily submit your app. For template10 you will need to read documentation and it takes some time and requires user to be familiar with Win app dev.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what SplitView means, but I still have a lot to learn. The word makes me think of when 2 apps are sharing the screen, but i guess thats not what You mean, but I think I can find some answers on Google. The tutorial You recommend looks good so far, and it was also the one I found myself :)

Comment: SplitView means kind of like hamburger slider menu. Its a new feature introduced in windows 10. Best of luck for your app then.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Looking forward to get started, so thanks again.